# Find entry in dataset using dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dataset

I use dataset in python to create and query databases.
It takes dictionaries to create an entry:

```
entry1={}; entry[id]=1;entry[name]='a'
DBd['data'].insert(entry1)
```

I would like to make sure that I do not enter the entry if it already exists.
However, the find method doesn't take dictionaries, but would work as follows:

```
DB['data'].find(id=1,name='a')
```

is there some way that I could do something like

```
DB['data'].find(entry1)
```

i.e. I would need to convert the dictionary into a valid filter.

Comment: I don't get it. Are you trying to write your own ORM? Why not use Django or SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn a dictionary into parameters using `**kwargs` parameters like this:

```
DB['data'].find(**entry1)
```